# Reciving only one byte with recv()

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, server, client

Creating a tcp client <-> server program in c for my home exam. Been running into some problems with reciev and sending data between the server and client. I'm only able to receive one byte, feks if i send "abcd" i receive "a".

(This is happening both ways since i'm using same methods for server and client)

Dont know if it is the sending part thats the problem or receiving

This is my code:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

char* recived_message;

int send_data(int socket, char* data){
    int offset = 0, len = strlen(data);

    while (offset != len) {
        int nb = send(socket, data + offset, len - offset, 0);

        if (nb < 0){
            perror("send");
            return -1;
        }
        offset += nb;
    }

    return 0;
}

int recive(int socket){
    int offset = 0;

    recived_message = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    memset(recived_message, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    while (offset != BUFFER_SIZE) {
        int nb = recv(socket, received_message + offset, BUFFER_SIZE - offset, 0);

        if(nb == -1){
            perror("read");
            return -1;

        }else if(nb == 0){
            return -1;
        }

        offset += nb;
    }

    printf("%d\n", offset);

    return 0;
}

char* get_data(){
    return recived_message;
}
```

Server side

```
int recive_data(int socket){
    char* buffer;

    if(recive(socket) != 0){
        return -1;
    }

    *buffer = *get_data();

    printf("socket %d: %s\nlength: %lu%", fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));

    return 0;
}
```

Part of client

```
char* test = "abcd";

for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    send_data(sock, test);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: You correctly receive in a loop, which is good, but every time you iterate in the loop you will overwrite the previous data in the buffer. You do it right when sending, why not when receiving?

Comment: As for the problem you are having, please show us how you *use* this code? How do toy know that you only receive a single byte? How do you check this? And try to send something where every character is unique, right now it's impossible to say if it's the first or the last character you see. Oh, and are you sure the problem is with the receiving and not the sending?

Comment: Your sending (at least) is wrong, you pass a 5 bytes long buffer `"abcd"`, but try to sends `BUFFER_SIZE` (1024) bytes... How are you sure that you only receive a single byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
*buffer = *get_data();
```

You dereferences the pointer returned by `get_data()` to get only the first element pointer to by the pointer.

And it's worse than that, because you dereference the uninitialized variable `buffer` to write that single character. This will lead to *undefined behavior*. Also, the later functions calls using this uninitialized variable also leads to undefined behavior.

The simple solution to (almost) all your problems: Assign to the actual variable:

```
buffer = get_data();
```

And I say that the above solves *almost* all your problems, because what if the terminating zero of the string isn't transmitted? That will also lead to UB (Undefined Behavior). If the data you receive is always a string, then you should make sure it's terminated, preferably in the `receive` function:

```
int recive(int socket){
    ...
    received_message[offset] = '\0';
    return 0;
}
```